# Python pandas: elegant division within dataframe

Tags: python

I'm new on stackoverflow and have switched from R to python. I'm trying to do something probably not too difficult, and while I can do this by butchering, I am wondering what the most pythonic way to do it is. I am trying to divide certain values (`E` where `F=a`) in a column by values further down in the column (`E` where `F=b`) using column `D` as a lookup:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'D':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1], 'E':[10,20,30,40,50,100, 250, 250, 360, 567, 400],'F':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']})
print(df)
out = pd.DataFrame({'D': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'a/b': [0.1, 0.08, 0.12 , 0.1111, 0.0881]}
print(out)
```

Can anyone help write this nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```py
df = df.set_index('D')
out = df.loc[(df['F'] == 'a'), 'E'] / df.loc[(df['F'] == 'b'), 'E']
out = out.reset_index()
```

Thanks for your thoughts - I got inspired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "using D column as lookup" since there is no need for such lookup in the example you provided.
However the quick and dirty way to achieve the output you did provide is

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'a/b': df[df['F'] == 'a']['E'].values / df[df['F'] == 'b']['E'].values})
output['D'] = df['D']
```

which makes `output` to be

```
        a/b  D
0  0.100000  1
1  0.080000  2
2  0.120000  3
3  0.111111  4
4  0.088183  5
```

Comment: Thanks. The column D is needed to match the values in E, I see I should have mixed them up a bit more to make it clearer: This df2 should give the same result as the df.
`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1], 'E':[10,20,30,40,50, 567, 100, 250, 360, 250, 400],'F':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']})`

Answer (score 0):

Lookup with `.loc` in pandas dataframe as `df.loc[rows, columns]` where the conditions for rows and columns are **True**

```
import numpy as np

# get indices from column D. I convert it to a list structure to make sure that the order is maintained.
idx = list(set(df['D']))
# A is an array of values with 'F'=a
A = np.array([df.loc[(df['F']=='a') & (df['D']==i),'E'].values[0] for i in idx])
# B is an array of values with 'F'=b
B = np.array([df.loc[(df['F']=='b') & (df['D']==i),'E'].values[0] for i in idx])

# Now devide towards your new dataframe of divisions
out = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([A/B,idx]).T, columns = ['a/b','D'])
```

Instead of using numpy.vstack, you can use:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(A/B,idx).T
out.columns = ['a/b','D']
```

with the same result. I tried to do it in a single line (for no reason whatsoever)

Comment: Great, this looks good and also returns the same result for `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1], 'E': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 567, 100, 250, 360, 250, 400],
                    'F': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']})
`
. Is there also a way to do it purely inside pandas?

Comment: yes, you make A and B pandas dataframes instead of arrays and then join them with `pandas.concat(df_A, df_B, axis=1)`. There other also ways.